# Why is this error happening with prepareForSegue in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

[image: There is this horrible error going on in my app]

I created a navigation controller and put 2 view controllers linked to it. One is called FirstLaunchVC and the other is FirstLaunchVC2, I want the user to put his name in the text field nameTxtField and when he clicks on the continueBtn it should lead to the other. In this second view (FirstLaunchVC2) there is a label called nameGreetings which will show the name of the user as a greeting with prepareForSegue, the thing is that it's crashing, saying that there are breakpoints on the line of the performSegueWithIdentifier and on the line where I write "nextVC.nameGreetings.text = "(str) etc etc". I have no clue why, can anyone help me with that? Btw, I've already checked the identifier and it's correct.

Comment: Oh yeah, right, like we're supposed to be able to see some tiny screen shot? Do not show _pictures_ of code. Show _code_.

Comment: Sorry, no need to be rude

Comment: Yes, Matt's sarcasm is inappropriate, but his point is valid. Your screen snapshot is extremely hard to read. And one of the purposes of Stack Overflow is to become a searchable resource for future readers, and images are pretty useless in that context. Please remove the image and replace it with the actual code and the text of the error message (and any or messages that might appear in the console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `nameGreetings` an `IBOutlet`? You cannot set the `IBOutlet` controls for the destination view controller in `prepareForSegue` of the originating view controller because while the destination view controller has been instantiated, its views and `IBOutlet` references have not. The `prepareForSegue` should feel free to update `String` properties of the destination, but not its `IBOutlet` references.

So updating of `name` is fine, but the `nameGreetings` should not be set in `prepareForSegue`, but rather that should be deferred until the the `viewDidLoad` of that `FirstLaunchVC2`.

Comment: It solved my problem, thanks! Yes, nameGreetings was an IBOutlet, thats why it was crashing. Thanks so muchhh